# How to run a cfquery within the onRequestStart() function?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I want to run a query on every page that a user requests. This query is needed to get back preferences set by the user's organisation for the application. This is what I have tried:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean">
  <cfargument type="String" name="TargetPage" required="true"/> 
<cfquery name="rsSettings">
SELECT *
FROM
dbo.Settings
</cfquery>
<cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
</component>
```

However each pages that looks for the `rsSettings` recordset says that its not defined. If I put the same query within each page that needs it then it works fine.

Does `onRequestStart()` not handle cfquery?

Comment: Yes, of course it does. If it didn't, you'd get an error. However `onRequestStart()` doesn't dictate which scope your variables go in: that's up to you to deal with. If you need data to be available request-wide, then you need to put the data in a scope that is available request-wide. As @OagerMouzer points out: say the request scope. That said, the sort of data you are exposing there looks application-specific, not request specific?

Comment: Are the settings likely to change from request to request? Might be a better idea to put the results into the session or application scope if they will not change much.

Comment: @AdamCameron It is application-scope for each unique company that uses the application. I don't know how to set application scope uniquely for each customer that uses the application. You did mention about naming the application for each company, but I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: @ScottStroz The settings may change while a user is using the application. A user account is associated with a company account. The company account has preferences stored against it. So say an employee is trying to process 100 orders but the company admin change the preferences to only allow a maximum of 50 orders, then this should change immediately. Or else people who have not logged out will continue to process things that are outside of the company rules.

Comment: If I belong to Company X, how does your application know that?

Comment: @DanBracuk It knows it because your user account has a CompanyID associated with it. So when you log-in, it will then check the preferences table against your CompanyID and bring those back.

Comment: Are you persisting the CompanyID anywhere, such as the session scope?  If so, you should use it to filter your query results.  IE you should have a where clause.

Comment: You could store the company settings in application scope (based on the ID of the company). To make sure these are up to date, simply add something to the process that persists this company data to update the values in the application scope. Pretty simple process, actually. Hell, if you are using ORM (which I doubt you are) you can even cache the company objects themselves.

Comment: @DanBracuk it will have a where clause eventually. I was just trying to make it work in the onRequestStart() function hence the original posted question.

Comment: @ScottStroz So if I was to store preferences in the application scope per companyID, when would I delete these application variables to free up memory? I could only do it when all the users of a company have logged out right? From the CF docs it says `If many users access the application simultaneously and you use Application scope variables extensively, your application performance might degrade. If your application uses many application variables, consider whether the variables must be in the Application scope or whether they can be Session or Request scope variables.`

Comment: How much data are you talking about? You can store a lot of data in shared scopes before you see memory issues. Also, storing data in shared scopes is far more efficient that running a query on EVERY page request.

Comment: You can even store this data using `cfcache` which will give better performance than running the query on every request, yet not potentially lead to memory issues of shared scopes. Same caveat, though, when things changes, you will need to update the cache.

Comment: Simple solution: 

Wrap this stuff up in a CFC. On application start, have the CFC run a query that populates an internal structure, keyed by company id.

On request, run a function on the CFC (getPreferencesForUser() ?) that uses session (yeah, go ahead and do it, we're not going to get into something like a session facade and DI in this thread...) to return preferencesByCompany[ session.companyId ].

When a user does something that changes the company's preferences, run a function on that CFC (refreshPreferencesForCompany(id)) that re-queries and update that company's preferences.

Comment: @JoeRinehart I like your suggestion a lot but is my concern about having the preferences (some 50-100 preferences) in the application scope for over 200+ companies not important? I'll end up with 2000 application scope variables.

Comment: Unless each of 'variable' holds a lot of data, that really is not much. Again, look into `cfcache` might be the solution you seek.

Comment: Memory-wise, that's not much. Let's pretend we have a worst-case: each is a 50 byte string (when most are probably 1-bit booleans). 50 bytes x 2000 = 100,000 bytes = 100kb. In a day and age where we're moving gigabyte databases into RAM, who cares?

Comment: @JoeRinehart Okay, that sounds fair. However you're saying store the variables in the application scope and then copy them to session scope. Why not keep them in application scope and do if/else statements against what CompanyID the user has stored in his session? Or else whenever the application scope variable get updated using `refreshPreferencesForCompany(companyid)` I'll have to also update the session variables for EVERY user thats in that company. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Heh, yeah. No need to deal with the session scope. Just have preferencesByCompany( companyId ) return the struct from the application scope. 

(Also, store the CFC -itself- in the application scope.)

Comment: Why on Earth would you use an if/else to get the data? If you store the data in a structure where each key is the id of a company you merely need to do: `application.companySettings[ companyId ]` to get the settings. Of course you also need to check if the key exists first, if not create it, then return it.

Comment: @JoeRinehart and Scotts suggestions are what I would work towards.  I simply provided a straight up answer it's nasty but it will work.  A structure with a key index or some persistent object in the application scope would be much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfquery name="request.rsSettings">
    SELECT *
    FROM
    dbo.Settings
</cfquery>
```

Then in the page use:

```
 request.rsSettings.columName
```

Comment: Oh I see. I thought it was stored in the VARIABLES scope like normal query.

Comment: Running this query on every page request to avoid the potential of memory issues is not something I would suggest. I have worked on applications with similar requirements and storing the information in the Application scope was more than adequate.

Comment: @volumeone with out specifying the scope, the query was stored in the variables scope, of the application.cfc. This private scope of the application object isn't visible to other parts of the request